# Input path does not exist error apache spark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am beginner in learning spark. I am following a book "Learning Spark By Holden Karau, Andy Konwinski,Patrick Wendell & Matei Zaharia".

In this book an example of python code is given

```
>>> lines = sc.textFile("README.md") # Create an RDD called lines
>>> lines.count() # Count the number of items in this RDD
127
>>> lines.first() # First item in this RDD, i.e. first line of README.md
u'# Apache Spark'
```

I want to know where is file "README.md" is present? as no information is given in the book. Moreover, whenever I try to run this code there is an error 
"Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/README.md"

I am running this code on Codera virtual machine for spark on vmware workstation.

Comment: You need to provide the correct path of the file.. ! The example is for the case when you have downloaded Spark Code and built it for itself then you would found README in the same folder. So what you can do is place a text file there with some data and then provide the path as you are providing ! The File should be present at the path : hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/filename

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava thank you for your response. Can you please tell me ho I can access the path: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/filename to place the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was using cloudera virtual machine for spark so the file README.md was not present at path "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/README.md". Now, I have used

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/README.md")
```

Spark will access file present at path "/home/cloudera/Desktop/README.md" from local file system.